# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: "binder" has no deployed releases

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployed a helm chart as shown below:

[image]

When I try to run the `helm upgrade` command, I get the following error:

[image]

I tried using the `--force` option too but still the same.

How can I rectify this error?

Comment: in your upgrade command you are not providing namespace

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7160

Answer (score 4):

For helm3, `helm uninstall --namespace $NAMESPACE $RELEASE_NAME`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this issue pop up, when I had 10+ failed releases. I had to manually [delete / patch](https://jacky-jiang.medium.com/how-to-fix-helm-upgrade-error-has-no-deployed-releases-mystery-3dd67b2eb126) release secrets.

This is however fixed for version [3.9.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/commit/da8e7d25329f9539cf034588d5638099fd69fda9).

**TL;DR**

use Helm 3.9.0+

Answer (score 2):

Helm v3.7.2

```
helm upgrade --install
```

> -i, --install  if a release by this name doesn't already exist, run
> an install

Answer (score 2):

in my case, when one of the deployment try failed for broke connection,
on of upgrading suck Pending and not be rollbacked.

i try to find secret of helm based on this numbers:

```
amirio 15:36:18 @amirio:~/Documents/jenkins $ helm history -n ci jenkins

REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION      
14              Wed Dec 28 17:20:30 2022        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
15              Thu Dec 29 13:30:24 2022        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
16              Fri Jan  6 10:53:02 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
17              Sat Mar 18 22:26:49 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
18              Sat Mar 18 22:33:12 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
19              Sat Mar 18 22:36:53 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
20              Sat Mar 18 22:40:28 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
21              Sat Mar 18 22:45:39 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
22              Sun Mar 19 12:50:36 2023        superseded      jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Upgrade complete 
23              Wed Apr 12 15:28:24 2023        pending-upgrade jenkins-3.8.3   2.303.2         Preparing upgrade
```

the #23 is Buggy upgating, and can not be rollbacked.

To solve this problem, find all secrets of this deployment in this namespace and deployment name:

```
amirio 15:38:29 @amirio:~/Documents/jenkins $ kubectl -n ci get secret -A | grep jenkins
ci                 jenkins                                                                  Opaque                           2      114d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v14                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      104d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v15                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      104d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v16                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      96d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v17                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      24d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v18                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      24d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v19                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      24d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v20                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      24d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v21                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      24d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v22                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      24d
ci                 sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v23                                           helm.sh/release.v1               1      12m
```

and then delete secret by this command:

```
kubectl delete secret <<secret name goes here>>
```

then remove the #23 `sh.helm.release.v1.jenkins.v23` secret and problem solved.

Comment: Can you edit and add what command you used to remove the specific secret you found causing the issue? Thank you!

Comment: @cpres, yes, i was edit the post and add delete section to end of it,

Answer (score 1):

As per [this website](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/helm-has-no-deployed-releases):

> Helm 2 compares the current deployment manifest with the new one to apply the necessary patches. It does not, however, compare the state of the resources between the manifests.
> If a previous deployment failed, it is likely that the cluster has some missing resources. Prior to Helm 2.7.1, Helm will try to upgrade the deployment without installing the missing resources. To prevent this, as of version 2.7.1, Helm uses the latest successful deployment as the baseline for the upgrade. If there is no successful deployment to be found, the system returns the “helm has no deployed releases” error message.

so you can try to follow the solutions 1 and 3 mentioned [there](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/helm-has-no-deployed-releases) since you've tried to use the `--force` flag already.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

First, clean up the release. Please note the Kubernetes resources for the release including deployment will be deleted from the cluster and the pod will also be terminated.

```
helm uninstall --namespace <NAMESPACE> <RELEASE_NAME>
```

Apply a fresh install

```
helm install <RELEASE_NAME> -f myvalues.yaml --namespace <NAMESPACE>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error using helm 3.1.2. There was nothing to purge or delete, because it was a fresh installation.

Simple fix: I used the latest helm version, which in my case was **3.10.2**.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like helm isn’t seeing your release because you have a different default namespace. Try adding the namespace flag to your upgrade command

```
helm upgrade <release> <chart> --version <version_number> --values <values> --namespace <namespace>
```